# springBoot no me dice que no puede crear la tabla cuando añado el campo Integer year

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2

He creado un proyecto en SpringBoot 3.0.5 con el inicializador de la web Spring.io. he creado la siguiente clase:

```
package com.example.accessingdatajpa;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "coche1")
public class Coche {

    // atributos encapsulados
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;
    //private Integer yearManufacturer
    private Integer year;
}
```

He añadido las dependencias en el archivo xml para las bases de datos H2 y JPA persistencia y cuando lo ejecuto me indica que no se puede crear la tabla en la base de datos. En cambio si cambio "year" por otro nombre si me funciona.
¿Me podría explicar alguien el motivo?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: El problema es que intentas utilizar la palabra year como nombre de atributo y eso en algunos dialectos de SQL es una palabra reservada. Las posibles soluciones es utilizar por ejemplo lo que tienes comentado, yearManufacturer o si realmentes quieres que el atributo se llame year, puedes indicarle el campo de la BD al que va a pertenercer dicho atributo, `@Column(name = "anio")
private Integer year;`